# Sphinx error: "/lib64/libperconaserverclient.so.18: version `libperconaserverclient_16' not found (required by searchd)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx

I'm working with a Ruby-on-Rails site that uses Sphinx for searches. The searchd command seems to be missing a library. When I run

> searchd

from the command line to test if it's working properly,
I get

> searchd: /lib64/libperconaserverclient.so.18: version `libperconaserverclient_16' not found (required by searchd)

This despite the fact that libperconaserverclient.so.16 seems to be symbolically linked to /usr/lib64/libperconaserverclient.so.18 on the server.

Any ideas on how I might fix this?

Comment: How did you install sphinx? What linux disturibution are you using?? Might also consider https://serverfault.com/ instead. This seems more of a 'sysadmin' problem, rather than 'coding'.